# help with database modeling

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have two tables: one for areas (like science, sport, education), and another for professions (like scientist, designer, golf player). There is a foreign relationship between the two tables, which works without any problems at the moment.

But now I need another table to put "number of workers", "average age", "years in the company" (this list is possibly different for each profession). What is the best way to do this? Create another table? What would be the parent? Basically, it is a third statement.

```
CREATE TABLE group (  
    id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
    area varchar(30),  
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)

CREATE TABLE job (  
    ref int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
    jobid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    job varchar(50),  
    PRIMARY KEY (ref)  
)

    ALTER TABLE job
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_job
    FOREIGN KEY (jobid) REFERENCES group(id)  
    ON UPDATE CASCADE  
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Can you please expand on the purpose of your system data? Also, please post the create table of your existing tables. Thanks!

Comment: i want to make a drop-down select by category. At the moment only lack the third category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand I would set up a third table as follows

```
Table: Employee
First_Name varchar(30)
Last Name varchar(30)
Age (int(3))
Employment Date (DATE)
Active (Yes/No)
JobFK (Points to emprego.PK)
```

With this kind of setup you can use joins on your tables to calculate how many workers are in the same profession.  The average age of those employees, and how long they have been with the company.  Given more information about your current tables I could even describe the sql queries for that information.

Comment: first area > job > employee. I am not sure about the constrain. It can exists professions with particularities.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your code then.  English also helps.  The above table should work if you constrain the right foreign key to the appropriate primary key on another table.

As I see it.  An employee has a Job.  A Job exists in a Profession. 
    Employee.JobFK -> Emprego.PK
    Emprego.FK -> Agrupamento.PK

Comment: i edited my code to English. The point of the question is: for example. A golf player doesn't have a contract with a company (suppose), and a doctor have.